# Keep rows with specific text and delete all the rest of rows in all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to keep rows with specific words and delete the rest but I have two problems. I'm not an expert in Excel VBA so I need your help.

1. I'm trying to keep rows that contain more than one text.(How to add text 1, text 2, Text 3). In the code below it's only one word(Text).
2. There are 27 sheets and some sheets are hidden and all data in each sheet is in table format. The code below for some reason gives error when I'm trying with table format. It works when it's applied to non-table format though.

How can I fix these two issues in this code?

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").Value) <> "Text" Then
            Worksheets(n).Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
 Next n
 End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Any error messages? "*The code does not work*" is not a good error description.

Comment: This code works but not the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never assigned a some variables..

This should do it and stop before the header row (row 1):

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim iBottomRow As Long, iRow As Long

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    iBottomRow = WS.Range("A" & Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Row
    For iRow = iBottomRow To 2 Step -1
        If WS.Range("A" & iRow).Value <> "Text" Then
            WS.Range("A" & iRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me an error: run error time 1004, Application defined or Object defined error

Answer (score 0):

If you only search values in column "A" try this.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
 Dim i As Long, L As Long
 Dim WS As Worksheet

  For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    L = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To L
        If WS.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "Text" And L > 0 Then
            WS.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
            L = L - 1
        End If
    Next i
  Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: This gave me an error: run error time 1004, Application defined or Object defined error

Comment: You need to put this code in a VBA module not in a Worksheet object.